# travel advice on visiting nusa lembongan and gili island from bali

Tags: bali

Well ... it would be great if we can be guided or advised what to do upon on the following. Il keep it simple for understanding.

We are travelling to paradise Bali from 
12th to 19th of September, landing on 12th - 9pm at the airport.

How's the weather out there in September ? Is it the write time to travel ?
On 13th morning planning for nusa lembongan island. 
2.1 how can I get there fast ?
2.2 can I snorkel in that island ?
2.3 is two days enough to discover the island ?

From nusa lembongan - planning for gili island.

3.1 - how can I go to gili island from nusa lembongan ? Travel time ?
3.2 planning to stay there for 3 days.
3.3 which island is better to spend more days ?
3.4 - very important 
Travel distance from gili island back to kuta ?
Is there a flight I can use ? Or speed boat ?
( Cause I heard it takes 4 hours )
Or any speed boat.

Kindly suggest and advise on the above.
It will be of a great help.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Sorry, you are asking (too) many questions in one, and it looks like several of those can be found yourself.

Comment: Please take the [tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) to better understand how questions are structured on the StackExchange sites.